# UI Theme Limitations - How to request changes?

Tags: theme

I really enjoy making themes for Blender, but my intention always falls short due to a few limitations that are in the theming system. As granular as the system is, there are a few options that control more than one item seemingly unnecessarily and so on.

It would be great to have this addressed, but I have no idea how to submit my request/documentation to Blender.

Thanks

Comment: Probably best to bring your ideas up on [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/) first and see if there's any enthusiasm for your proposals. Here is definitely not the right place for it!

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For suggestions and feature requests use https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect or https://blenderartists.org. Before doing so consider that ideas are a dime-a-dozen, what we lack is manpower. Every single one of the millions of users have their own long list of personal wishes and desires, while comparatively very few people have the knowledge and inclination to actually implement them.

Comment: Are you saying that they don't want feedback?

Comment: @Atheneo No, the developers want feedback but they cannot implementd every feature requested. If other users like your request it can get up voted and this will increase the chances that it will added in further versions of Blender.

Comment: Okay, well yeah it was not so much a demand but a notice of the limitations in the UI editor. I'll post it on the right-click select place. Thanks